# Как получить c помощью JavaScript атрибут "for" у тега "label"?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, for, label

Нам дана форма:

```
<form class="checkbox-form"> 
  <input class="checkbox-form__checkbox" type="checkbox" id="task-1">
  <label for="task-1"></label>
</form>
```

Как получить в console.log через JS значение атрибута "for" у тега "label" ?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ:

```
const getInput = document.querySelector('.checkbox-form');
const form = getInput.querySelector('label').htmlFor;
console.log(form);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]